# How to get ID from link, using Nativescript

Tags: javascript, angular, nativescript

How to get the id of this URL : 
http://domainpertest.tk/reset/11E89887FABBC1D

So when I click this link, I want to get this 11E89887FABBC1D

Any idea please?

Comment: Can you be more specific about where this URL appears? Is it hard-coded in an angular template, is it drawn from a database, is it part of an html page downloaded from the internet?

Comment: This link I open from email, I use nativescript-urlhandler and in ngOnInit() I handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {}); this appURL show me link. How to get only id? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use javascript `split` method for getting this id.

```js
var str = "http://domainpertest.tk/reset/11E89887FABBC1D";
var res = str.split("/");
console.log(res[res.length-1]);
```

Comment: This link I open from email, I use nativescript-urlhandler and in ngOnInit() I handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {}); this appURL show me link. How to get only id? Thank you!

Comment: You can also `str.split("/").reverse()[0]` reverse the order and get the first item.

Comment: Hello! I put this  `console.log('Got the following appURL', appURL);` and show my link, like `Got the following appURL http://domainpertest.tk/reset/11E89887FABBC1D` I don't use split because `Property 'split' does not exist on type 'AppURL'.ts(2339)`

Comment: can you please share your latest code. I wanna know your latest approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex or extract substring with `url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/"), url.length-1)`

Comment: This link I open from email, I use `nativescript-urlhandler` and in ngOnInit() I     `handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {});` this `appURL` show me link. How to  get only id? Thank you!

Comment: AppURL is your typed object of a string? If yes, you can just use `split` function, there is error/warning in ts, but it's fine when running.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function findIdInUrl() {
  var url="http://domainpertest.tk/reset/11E89887FABBC1D";
  return url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
}
```

Comment: I use nativescript-urlhandler and in ngOnInit() I handleOpenURL((appURL: AppURL) => {}); this appURL show me link  like Got the following appURL http://domainpertest.tk/reset/11E89887FABBC1D I don't use split because Property 'split' does not exist on type 'AppURL'.ts(2339)